# Force Android Emulator to trust self-signed certificate

Tags: android, asp.net-core, ssl, xamarin.forms

I have an api service(.Net Core 3.1) for now located on my local dev machine and Android client app created with Xamarin. This service have my custom domain with https configured https://example.com:5001. Also I configured self-signed certificate for this service and on my machine Chrome display this domain as secured.

But I faced a problem with Android emulator. Emulator already configured to access example.com. When I'm trying to access https://example.com:5001/anyaction via Chrome I'm getting a warning that the site is `"Your connection to this site is not secure"`.

Also I should say that I installed my self-signed certificate to emulator.

Also when I'm trying to send a request to this domain via `HttpClient`. I'm getting an error `"Failed to connect"` after timeout, I believe it is related to problems with SSL.

How could I force Android Emulator to trust my self signed certificate?

**UPD**: I found that certificate is installed but not displayed in Trusted Credentials. How could I install in correctly?

Comment: I do not know what tutorials you refer to. I learnt about it from [this](https://support.kaspersky.com/CyberTrace/1.0/en-US/174127.htm).

Comment: @u1986237This article is related to desktop, not android